# php open dynamic link in new window with iframe

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to figure out how to make it so when someone clicks a link on my search results it will open in a new window and in the new window have an iframe that displays the url. I am not sure how to go about doing this. I have

```
$row['url']
```

that displays the url for each result to use.

To be more specific I am trying to do what filestube does. I like the feature a lot and would like to use something like it on my site. Here is an example url to show you want I mean http://www.filestube.com/5a4c10249bd9fce003e9/go.html

when the link is clicked on filestube it will open a page like this. I have seen lots of sites do this but filestube is what pops in my head right now. Can anyone provide me with a code example or try to explain how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to a URL inside of your application, example `my_url.php` and post to it in parameters the URL you want to show. Than in that script, load an iFrame with that URL.

Example of `my_url.php?url=http://www.google.ca`:

```
<div>You Header</div>
<iframe src="<?php $_GET['url']"></iframe>
<div>Your Footer</div>
```

Comment: I will try that and see if I can accomplish this.

Comment: i tried this $go = "go.php?url="; and made my link like this print "<a href=".$go."".($row['url'])." rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>".html_entity_decode($row['title'])."</a>"; and on go.php i put this <iframe src="<?php $_GET['url']?></iframe>. on go.php inside the iframe it says "The requested URL /</iframe was not found on this server.". I am not sure what to do but I will keep trying.

Comment: forgot the quote " at the end of iframe and now it just shows a blank white iframe. I will see if I can capture any data in it.

Comment: using $url = $_GET['url'];
print "$url";
it shows the correct link on the page I just have to get the iframe to load it.

Answer (score 1):

The link should point to another PHP page. Something like this.

```
<a href="/open-link.php?url=<?=urlencode('http://www.google.com')?>">http://www.google.com</a>
```

In your open-link.php, write your iframe code.

```
<iframe src="<?=$_GET['url']?>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have PHP file named external.php

1. Make that PHP file accept a $_GET parameter.
2. Pass the URL as a param
3. Use that URL to point the iframe in that PHP file to whatever URL is passed